# How to find an HTML element in array of HTML siblings of one parent ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, jsx

This is my code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
const [point, setPoint] = useState(null);
  function handleClick(e) {
       document.querySelector("#politscale").querySelectorAll("span").forEach(s => { s.style.backgroundColor = "grey"; })
      e.target.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      console.log(document.querySelector("#politscale").querySelectorAll("span"))
      setPoint( Array.prototype.indexOf.call(document.querySelector("#politscale").querySelectorAll("span"), e.target))
      cogoToast.success(point)
      console.log(point)
  }
useEffect(() => {
  document.querySelector("#politscale").querySelectorAll("span").forEach(s => {
    s.addEventListener("click", handleClick)
  })
}, [])
```

I have such a scale bar and I want to find the index of clicked element out of all other children in the parent element, so I can send it to backend later on:

```html
<Scale id="politscale">
              <span id="scaleControlUnit"></span>
              <span id="scaleControlUnit"></span>
              <span id="scaleControlUnit"></span>
              <span id="scaleControlUnit"></span>
              <span id="scaleControlUnit"></span>
            </Scale>
```

I think that there's a closure somewhere but I don't notice it! Whnerever I click, I get null, 2, 3. Yet the colora are setting correctly (red for actie, grey for all others). Please help me making out how to solve it!

Comment: All of your ids are the same - they should be unique, or even better, data attributes. Also you seem to be confusing vanilla JS with how React works.

Comment: Thanks, Andy, that's an idea! I think it will help me now!

Comment: `console.log(point)` logs the previous state not the state just changed by `setPoint`. As it was explained a million times on SO, `setState` is (usually) asynchronous (kind of; it's actually postponed).

Comment: I suggest reading some [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) before you go any further.

Comment: Thank you, @marzelin and @Andy! I'll view it now,Andy

Comment: anyway, React should be a layer between your code and the DOM. You shouldn't tinker with the DOM directly like adding listeners to it but instead add handlers to react elements.

Comment: I've solved it, it actually was setting, as you said, @marzelin, and it is actually async, now I now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React is a framework that is state-based - the state informs the render of the DOM. Trying to use querySelector and its equivalent won't work like you think it will.

So here's an example of this working.

1. We set the state to be the index of the span (initially nothing).
2. `handleClick` which is attached to the `div` (or would be attached to your `Scale` element) grabs the data id attribute from the span and adds it to the state.
3. This triggers the page to re-render, the spans get rebuilt, and depending on the state the `selected` class gets added.

There is no other DOM manipulation going on. React does all that heavy lifting for you.

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState} = React;

function Example() {

  // Set up state. You want to be saving the
  // index of the span you've selected
  const [index, setIndex] = useState();

  // handleClick takes the id of the span and
  // sets it to state (as a number, not a string)
  function handleClick(e) {
    const { target: { dataset: { id } } } = e;
    setIndex(+id);
  }

  // getSpans just creates the spans but
  // uses the state to identify which one should be selected
  function getSpans() {
    const arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      arr.push(
        <span className={index === i && 'selected'} data-id={i}>{i}</span>
      )
    }
    return arr;
  }

  return (
    <div onClick={handleClick}>
      {getSpans()}
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
span { background-color: grey; padding: 1em;}
.selected { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Way less code but way better result, thanks again! I'll stick up to this solution!